# So uhh..I think I broke gradle

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

All I did was take a break from Android Studios for about a week. Seriously. That's it. Now gradle is throwing me ol "Could not load wrapper properties...Illegal character in scheme name at index 15" which happens to be my distribution url. But I never changed that. And when I go into the gradle options under settings, it says my gradle location is incorrect. But again, I didn't change anything and that is, indeed, where my gradle file is located. I've been stuck on this for hours and can't find any decent documentation on the issue. I'm fairly new to this whole gradle thing so I apologize if it's a simple thing I'm overlooking.

EDIT:

Here's my gradle wrapper..

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-all.zip
```

Comment: You should probably share your gradle-wrapper.properties file to see if there is something wrong there. Also, if you are using your own distribution URL instead of Gradle's default, make sure that you can still download from there.

Comment: @DanielA.González , good call...editing now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a duplicate in "distributionUrl=distributionUrl=", that is probably the issue.